# Apt asks me "Which services should be restarted?", but won't accept my answer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

```
Restarting services...
Daemons using outdated libraries
--------------------------------

  1. containerd.service  4. fail2ban.service      7. networkd-dispatcher.service  10. systemd-logind.service  13. unattended-upgrades.service
  2. dbus.service        5. iscsid.service        8. polkit.service               11. systemd-manager         14. user@1001.service
  3. docker.service      6. ModemManager.service  9. rpcbind.service              12. udisks2.service         15. none of the above

(Enter the items or ranges you want to select, separated by spaces.)

Which services should be restarted?
```

I tried to answer according to the instructions, but none of these worked:

- 1-15
- 1 15
- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
- all
- y

Comment: Try `1-14` as the answer, as "none of the above" probably invalidates everything else.

Comment: Sounds good - I did not see this. I wish there was a `16: all` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option for `none of the above` probably can't be combined with or included in a range  of the specific services you want to restart, as those are mutually exclusive.

Valid input to select all options to select all would then be:

- `1-14`
- `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14`

As you already commented: there should be an option `16. all` as well.